# How can I add as many buttons as passed in prop number with out causing too many re-render on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

This should be relatively simple yet I can't figure it out. I want to render buttons dynamically depending on the prop that has been passed through the parent component. I can't ".map" since it is not an array and I cant seem to get my for loop to pass in React. Can I get some help please, what am I missing here on renderButtonsHandler()?

```js
const Carousel = ({ chunkSize }) => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const totalImages = imageArray.length;
  
  
  const renderButtonsHandler = (chunkSize) => {
    const buttons = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
      buttons.push(
        <button
          className="circleButton"
          key={i}
          onClick={setCurrentSlide(i)}
        ></button>
      );
    }
    return buttons;
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button  </button>
      {imageArray.map((img, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {index === currentSlide && (
              <img
                className="carouselImg"
                src={img}
                key={index}
                />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button></button>
      {renderButtonsHandler(chunkSize)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Please check out my answer, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this instead:

```
 return (
    <div className="container">
      <button  </button>
      {imageArray.map((img, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {index === currentSlide && (
              <img
                className="carouselImg"
                src={img}
                key={index}
                />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button></button>
      {[...Array(chunkSize).keys()].map(i)=>( 
         <button
          className="circleButton"
          key={i}
          onClick={setCurrentSlide(i)}
        ></button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can `.map` if `chunkSize` is a number. But you have to do it in different way.
You don't need function for that. You can just create new array, fill it with empty strings and map by that. Then just use it in code like:

```
   {new Array(chunkSize).fill("").map((item, i) => (
      <button
        key={i}
        className="circleButton"
        onClick={setCurrentSlide(i)}
      ></button>
    ))}
```

example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-i99eg?file=/index.js)